Where does the spelling "Lyu" originate for Lü?
Just saw Lyu, Huihui competing in the javelin event at the '24 Summer Olympics.
In Chinese her name is written as:

吕会会

吕 is generally romanized as Lü. Alternatively, Lv or even Lu can be seen as common romanizations.
Lyu certainly isn't part of Pinyin or Wade–Giles. My hunch is that this has something to do with character limitations using diacritics.
Where does "Lyu" originate from?

新版护照字母ü变YU. Since 2012, the last name 吕 in the passport can be officially spelled as lyu, instead of lu, which is for another last name 陆.
But it does not mean that lyu substitutes lü in Pinyin, which is official. Also in Pinyin, 鱼 is spelled as yu, not ü. This may be why people use lyu as a substitute for lü in their names.
Also, in some computer keyboard Pinyin input designs, lv is for 吕 绿 律 etc.
No matter what, those are just different ways to represent a syllable or a character. It does not have any impact on the pronunciation of the Chinese language.

Is nu (女) also becoming nyu?

If a person's last name is (女), then, I guess, it is spelled as nyu. But 百度 says that very few people have this last name.

I think 女 as a last name would be pretty hilarious.
